# How to retrieve digital signature information from PDF with PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I have app that needs to retrieve some data (signer name) from digital signature "attached" on PDF files.

I have found only examples in Java and C# using the iText class AcroFields method GetSignatureNames

**edit:** I've tried *pdftk* with dump_data_fields and generate_fpdf and the result was that (unfortunately):

```
/Fields [
<<
/V /dftk.com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDictionary@3048918
/T (Signature1)
>>]
```

and

```
FieldType: Signature
FieldName: Signature1
FieldFlags: 0
FieldJustification: Left
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Have you looked at the fdf functions?

Comment: If the solution @Dennis posted, doesn't work for you then let me know and I would like to give this question a shot

Comment: Have you considered looking into adding the c code as an extension to php?

Comment: Hi @TarunLalwani, the Dennis answer is almost complete but now I have some difficult to navigate on ASN1 tree from DER decode using PHPASN1

Comment: Share the current code that you have, i will give that part a short

Comment: @TarunLalwani : https://ideone.com/jKY5tK

Comment: @celsowm I've added another example code regarding your question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, it's complicated (I would say even impossible, but who knows) to achieve this only with PHP.

At first, please read [article about digital signature in Adobe PDF](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSig/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf)

Second, after reading this you will know that signature is stored between b and c bytes according to /ByteRange[a b c d] indicator

Third, we can extract b and c from document and then extract signature itself (guide says it will be hexdecoded PKCS7# object).

```
<?php

 $content = file_get_contents('test.pdf');

 $regexp = '#ByteRange\[\s*(\d+) (\d+) (\d+)#'; // subexpressions are used to extract b and c

 $result = [];
 preg_match_all($regexp, $content, $result);

 // $result[2][0] and $result[3][0] are b and c
 if (isset($result[2]) && isset($result[3]) && isset($result[2][0]) && isset($result[3][0]))
 {
     $start = $result[2][0];
     $end = $result[3][0];
     if ($stream = fopen('test.pdf', 'rb')) {
         $signature = stream_get_contents($stream, $end - $start - 2, $start + 1); // because we need to exclude < and > from start and end

         fclose($stream);
     }

     file_put_contents('signature.pkcs7', hex2bin($signature));
}
```

Forth, after third step we have PKCS#7 object in file signature.pkcs7. Unfortunately, I don't know methods to extract information from signature using PHP. So you must be able to run shell commands to use openssl

```
openssl pkcs7 -in signature.pkcs7 -inform DER -print_certs > info.txt
```

After running this command in file info.txt you will have a chain of certificates. Last one is the one you need. You can see the structure of the file and parse needed data.

Please also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700851/extract-certificate-from-a-pkcs7-signature-in-php), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102564/php-how-to-parse-pkcs7-signature-blob) and [this topic](http://qistoph.blogspot.bg/2012/01/manual-verify-pkcs7-signed-data-with.html)

**EDIT at 2017-10-09**
I knowingly advised you to see [exactly this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700851/extract-certificate-from-a-pkcs7-signature-in-php)
There is a code that you can adjust to your needs.

```
use ASN1\Type\Constructed\Sequence;
use ASN1\Element;
use X509\Certificate\Certificate;       

$seq = Sequence::fromDER($binaryData);
$signed_data = $seq->getTagged(0)->asExplicit()->asSequence();
// ExtendedCertificatesAndCertificates: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2315#section-6.6
$ecac = $signed_data->getTagged(0)->asImplicit(Element::TYPE_SET)->asSet();
// ExtendedCertificateOrCertificate: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2315#section-6.5
$ecoc = $ecac->at($ecac->count() - 1);
$cert = Certificate::fromASN1($ecoc->asSequence());
$commonNameValue = $cert->tbsCertificate()->subject()->toString();
echo $commonNameValue;
```

I've adjusted it for you, but please make the rest by yourself.

Comment: unfortunately the preg_match_all fails to this pdf with my signature: https://www.docdroid.net/oVB1AW2/

Comment: @celsown Why you did not bother to take a look to the contents of your test.pdf file? Your ByteRange indicator is a bit different, you just need to slightly change `$regexp = '#ByteRange\s*\[(\d+) (\d+) (\d+)#';`

Comment: the new regex worked, thanks. Now I am trying to use PHPASN1 to decode the DER because apparently PHP openssl does not work with DER

Comment: @DenisAlimov you just led this guy down a _very_ deep rabbit-hole, and back out of it, with 3 specific instructions. Well done!

Comment: @TonyChiboucas yep, thank you. but I would rather implement java service using 3rd party libraries for this issue. and use it via shell command

Comment: If you're going to call it via shell, why not just write a shell script instead?

Comment: $commonNameValue = $cert->tbsCertificate()->subject()->firstValueOf("commonName");

var_dump($commonNameValue->stringValue());

Comment: @celsowm please see how to extract common name from signer cerificate

Comment: @celsowm Thanks for updated regex. It saves my day. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DenisAlimov It's actually possible to achieve this with PHP only. Also, your solution doesn't work for PDF files signed by 2 or more people. Please, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75891895/1657502

Answer (score 3):

This is my working code in PHP7:

```
<?php


require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use Sop\ASN1\Type\Constructed\Sequence;
use Sop\ASN1\Element;
use Sop\X509\Certificate\Certificate;  



$currentFile = "./upload/test2.pdf";


$content = file_get_contents($currentFile);


$regexp = '/ByteRange\ \[\s*(\d+) (\d+) (\d+)/'; // subexpressions are used to extract b and c

$result = [];
preg_match_all($regexp, $content, $result);

// $result[2][0] and $result[3][0] are b and c
if (isset($result[2]) && isset($result[3]) && isset($result[2][0]) && isset($result[3][0])) {
    $start = $result[2][0];
    $end = $result[3][0];
    if ($stream = fopen($currentFile, 'rb')) {
        $signature = stream_get_contents($stream, $end - $start - 2, $start + 1); // because we need to exclude < and > from start and end

        fclose($stream);
    }

    
    $binaryData = hex2bin($signature);
    
    $seq = Sequence::fromDER($binaryData);
    $signed_data = $seq->getTagged(0)->asExplicit()->asSequence();
    // ExtendedCertificatesAndCertificates: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2315#section-6.6
    $ecac = $signed_data->getTagged(0)->asImplicit(Element::TYPE_SET)->asSet();
    // ExtendedCertificateOrCertificate: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2315#section-6.5
    $ecoc = $ecac->at($ecac->count() - 1);
    $cert = Certificate::fromASN1($ecoc->asSequence());
    $commonNameValue = $cert->tbsCertificate()->subject()->toString();
    echo $commonNameValue;

    
}
```

Composer:

```
{
    "require": {
        "sop/asn1": "^4.1",
        "sop/x509": "^0.7.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: If possible, include the "composer requirements" too

Comment: yes please, how to doing this without composer autoload file?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46603440/1657502) proposed by [@Denis Alimov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1865655/denis-alimov), but using just PHP functions (instead of the **[openssl](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/openssl-pkcs7.1ssl.html)** command) and no Composer dependencies:

```php
<?php
function der2pem($der_data) {

    // https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php

    $pem = chunk_split(base64_encode($der_data), 64, "\n");
    $pem = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n".$pem."-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
    return $pem;
}

function extract_pkcs7_signatures($path_to_pdf) {

    // https://stackoverflow.com/q/46430367

    $pdf_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_pdf);

    $regexp = '/ByteRange\ \[\s*(\d+) (\d+) (\d+)/';

    $result = [];
    preg_match_all($regexp, $pdf_contents, $result);

    $signatures = [];

    if (isset($result[0])) {
        $signature_count = count($result[0]);
        for ($s = 0; $s < $signature_count; $s++) {
            $start = $result[2][$s];
            $end = $result[3][$s];
            $signature = null;
            if ($stream = fopen($path_to_pdf, 'rb')) {
                $signature = stream_get_contents($stream, $end - $start - 2, $start + 1);
                fclose($stream);
                $signature = hex2bin($signature);
                $signatures[] = $signature;
            }
        }
    }

    return $signatures;
}

function who_signed($path_to_pdf) {

    // https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.certparams.php
    // https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-read.php
    // https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-parse.php

    $signers = [];

    $pkcs7_der_signatures = extract_pkcs7_signatures($path_to_pdf);
    if (!empty($pkcs7_der_signatures)) {
        $parsed_certificates = [];
        foreach ($pkcs7_der_signatures as $pkcs7_der_signature) {
            $pkcs7_pem_signature = der2pem($pkcs7_der_signature);
            $pem_certificates = [];
            $result = openssl_pkcs7_read($pkcs7_pem_signature, $pem_certificates);
            if ($result) {
                foreach ($pem_certificates as $pem_certificate) {
                    $parsed_certificate = openssl_x509_parse($pem_certificate);
                    $parsed_certificates[] = $parsed_certificate;
                }
            }
        }

        // Remove certificate authorities certificates

        $people_certificates = [];
        foreach ($parsed_certificates as $certificate_a) {
            $is_authority = false;
            foreach ($parsed_certificates as $certificate_b) {
                if ($certificate_a['subject'] == $certificate_b['issuer']) {
                    // If certificate A is of the issuer of certificate B, then
                    // certificate A belongs to a certificate authority and,
                    // therefore, should be ignored
                    $is_authority = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!$is_authority) {
                $people_certificates[] = $certificate_a;
            }
        }

        // Remove duplicate certificates

        $distinct_certificates = [];
        foreach ($people_certificates as $certificate_a) {
            $is_duplicated = false;
            if (count($distinct_certificates) > 0) {
                foreach ($distinct_certificates as $certificate_b) {
                    if (
                        ($certificate_a['subject'] == $certificate_b['subject']) &&
                        ($certificate_a['serialNumber'] == $certificate_b['serialNumber']) &&
                        ($certificate_a['issuer'] == $certificate_b['issuer'])
                    ) {
                        // If certificate B has the same subject, serial number
                        // and issuer as certificate A, then certificate B is a
                        // duplicate and, therefore, should be ignored
                        $is_duplicated = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!$is_duplicated) {
                $distinct_certificates[] = $certificate_a;
            }
        }

        foreach ($distinct_certificates as $certificate) {
            $signers[] = $certificate['subject']['CN'];
        }
    }

    return $signers;
}

$path_to_pdf = 'test.pdf';

// In case you want to test the extract_pkcs7_signatures() function:

/*
$signatures = extract_pkcs7_signatures($path_to_pdf);
for ($s = 0; $s < count($signatures); $s++) {
    $path_to_pkcs7 = pathinfo($path_to_pdf, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . $s . '.pkcs7';
    file_put_contents($path_to_pkcs7, $signatures[$s]);
    echo shell_exec("openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in $path_to_pkcs7 -print_certs -text");
}
exit;
*/

var_dump(who_signed($path_to_pdf));
?>
```

For some `test1.pdf`, signed by just one person (let's call her `ALICE`), this script should return:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "ALICE"
}
```

For some `test2.pdf`, signed by two people (let's call them `BOB` and `CAROL`), this script should return:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "BOB"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "CAROL"
}
```

For more information, take a look at this question of mine:

- [PHP - how to get the signer(s) of a digitally signed PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75889572/1657502)

Comment: change regex to '#ByteRange\[\s*(\d+) (\d+) (\d+)#'; in order to works.

Answer (score -2):

I've used iText and found it to be very reliable, I highly recommend it.
you can always call the java code as a "microservice" from PHP.

Comment: Please share more details, like some code that could help to understand your answer

Comment: At the time I wrote the code, the code belonged to an employer, so I can't share it.
java can be called from php, as for the code examples, i Think iText has good docs online, I would invite those interested to review iText, although, who knows, 5 years later maybe there is now a PHP way of doing it which actually parses the binary the right way.